# Simpler method to pass Authorization header with Volley Android

Tags: android, request, android-volley

I familiarised myself with passing authorization headers in android using volley library with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000212/how-to-send-authorization-header-in-android-using-volley-library).
The problem is if i have to send multiple requests i need to pass it with each requestwhich makes the code longer.
My question is how can i modify the ServerRequest/Request class to make sure the parameters are passed everytime i make a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Singleton Volley class as described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41120064/1371792).

So you will not need to add header everytime when you post your volley request